# How to calculate the proportion of values in one column, which don't match with values in another?

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe that I got by using full_join:

```
col1  col2
11    11
12    NA
14    14
NA    17
NA    18
NA    NA
NA    NA
```

I want to calculate proportions of values in each column which don't match with another column. For example, here for col1 it will be 1/3. since it is only value 12, which doesn't match and is not NA. For col2 it will be 2/4, since there are 17 and 18 which doest match with value in col1 and are not NA. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a one time comparison between two columns to simply get two numbers:

```r
df <- tribble(
    ~col1,  ~col2,
    11,    11,
    12,    NA,
    14,    14,
    NA,    17,
    NA,    18,
    NA,    NA,
    NA,    NA
)

mean(!df$col1[!is.na(df$col1)] %in% df$col2) # 0.333

mean(!df$col2[!is.na(df$col2)] %in% df$col1) # 0.5
```

Comment: and is it possible to write it as a proportion, not as a percentage (to see real numbers)?

Comment: If you want the actual "1/3" string you could do `paste0(sum(!df$col1[!is.na(df$col1)] %in% df$col2), "/", length(df$col1[!is.na(df$col1)]))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr.

For column 1:

```
df %>% summarise(col1_in_col2 = sum(!col1 %in% col2) / sum(!is.na(col1))
```